# Displaying a jgrowl message after X seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgrowl

I'm implementing jgrowl on my website, but did not find any indication on the plugin's website nor on the internet on how to display the message with a lag. Ideally I'd like the Jgrowl message to appear 10 seconds after the page loads. Is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {   
    if($.cookie("new_visitor") != "true") {
        $.cookie("new_visitor", "true", { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        $.jGrowl("A message with a header", { header: 'Important' });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what about using a timeout?...

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exactly what the others said. See it in code.

```
$(function () { 
    if($.cookie("new_visitor") !== "true") {

        $.cookie("new_visitor", "true", { expires: 1, path: '/' });

        setTimeout(function(){
            $.jGrowl("A message with a header", { header: 'Important' });
        },10000);  // display after 10 seconds
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help

Comment: Agreed, the setTimeout() is the best thing to do. If you find yourself doing this a lot, or for every notification then you could consider creating a wrapper function for jGrowl.